# Approximately Aligning 2 Lists

Tags: python

I have 2 lists that consist in valley occurrences of 2 time series that are shifted in time. The problem is that the valley finding algorithm is not consistent, i.e. it will find 3 valleys for time series 1 and 4 valleys say for time series 2. The result is the following:

```
x = [7, 14, 18, 22]
y = [0, 9, 15, 19, 23, 35]
```

My goal is to try and align both lists intelligently, that is, match 7 with 9, 14 with 15, etc. and obtain:

```
x = [7, 14, 18, 22] 
y = [9, 15, 19, 23]
```

**2 notes**

- Outliers like 0 and 35 don't have to appear at the beginning or end, they can appear anywhere in the list.
- Shifts can be greater than 2. They can be 3, 4 or even 5 which may cause interference with other elements in the list.

Is there a smart and fast way of doing this? Would appreciate some guidance.

My approach so far if I assume a maximum deviation of 2:

```
# pass number 1
p1 = [y + 1 for y in y]
p2 = [y - 1 for y in y]

best_guess = []
for i in range(len(y)):
    if p1[i] in x or p2[i] in x:
        best_guess.append(y[i])

# pass number 2
p1 = [y + 2 for y in y]
p2 = [y - 2 for y in y]

for i in range(len(y)):
    if p1[i] in x or p2[i] in x:
        if y[i] not in best_guess:
            best_guess.append(y[i])

# sort since always in increasing order
best_guess.sort()
```

Comment: What approaches have you tried? Why do/don't they work?

What is the point at which you would say that the shift is too large? For example, consider `x` from your example, and `y = [5, 9, 15, 19, 23]`. Should `x[0]` be aligned to `y[0]`?

Comment: This sounds "arbitrarily aligned" rather than "intelligently aligned". In your expected output, you've just used a face-value judgement to determine whether the values are approximately similar? You probably want to use some statistics to determine this. From your question as-is, I don't know what that approach might be.

Comment: I'd like to try different values of the shift and see which one works best I guess. I've tried a few things now but the've failed. My first attempt: I first determine the longer list since that's the one that must be modified. Then I compute that list + 1 and take any matches between both list. Do the same consecutively with +2 and +3. Didn't work too well.

Comment: @roganjosh mind clarifying what you mean by statistics?

Comment: Well what if `y` happened to contain the value 5? Should 7 be aligned with 9 or with 5? You would need to understand more about the nature of the misalignment. You could similarly have 23 and 25 in `y` and need to align 24 and 26 with that, which may be easy or difficult depending on how variable the misalignment was. In other words, your example could be too contrived and unless you do some preliminary work, you can't see what's a reasonable alignment and what's an outlier.

Comment: @Antimony I've added the method I've used for this dummy example.